# I having trouble to get the value of radio button in angular material

Tags: angular, api, angular-material, dotnetcorecli

```
<div class="col-md-4 pt-5">
   <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option validator" name="validatorStatus"                   
       [(ngModel)]="validatorStatus"  formControlName="validatorStatus" >
       <mat-radio-button value="true" checked>Approve</mat-radio-button>
       <mat-radio-button value="false">Reject</mat-radio-button>
   </mat-radio-group>
   <br>
   <mat-label> validator {{ validatorStatus}}</mat-label>
</div>
```

selected radiobutton value not showing in  {{ validatorStatus}},unable to find the solution

Comment: You are using a mix for form and data binding `[(ngModel)]="validatorStatus"  formControlName="validatorStatus"`, so it's hard to tell what causing the problem. You add your component.ts code in the question, and probably create a stackblitz to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: this is same thing working on stackblitz but not in my page, am I missing something

Comment: @sonaliborekarr Either use template-driven binding or reactive form binding, not both. Please post the component code where you create the reactive form.

Comment: @sonaliborekarr you should still post the stackblitz link in the question, its easier for everyone to see and execute your code.